# Facebook Login JDK Securely

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I am new to FB interaction and used FB recommended JDK approach to get login/continue as to work on webpage.  But i can't see how the login response is secure at all since it is all done in the client side. Again only concerned about login not post login calls as i see many methods for securing those. Am i missing something here that i can't see after combing thru the FB login documentation?   I am wondering if i crazy to consider using the Manual Login Flow which FB is clearly not promoting as much?

thanks for the help!

Comment: what exactly does not look secure to you? you will have to be a lot more specific.

Comment: So it seems the FB JDK login runs in entirely in the client side browser.  I'm using FB code to asynchronously  download the JDK and then to check logged in status as FB recommends.  If not logged in i'm using the standard facebook login button.  How do i know the login attempt response object in the client side browser truly came from FB and was not tampered with via the client side browser ?  So then based on this response object i post back to my server that the user is logged into Facebook... continue to logged in experience.  but i cannot see how this is secure.

Comment: transfer the access token to the server (and nothing else), use the graph api on the server with that access token to check for the user.

Comment: "tampered with via the client side browser" - well, if the user got some malicious plugin installed on his browser, security is void anyway...and if the user wants to do that on his own...well, try it and see if that works ;)

Comment: @luschn - i have been looking for a way to validate the access token in FB Developers documentation in regards to login security.  Your message let me know i was on the right track so thanks... I just could not find that easily in the canned Facebook Login Getting Started or the Login Security.  Thanks i believe this takes care of it.  Appreciate the help.

Comment: Well the access token returned with the response login doesn't seem to be a user level token... It seems to be an Application Access token.  It does not validate back to a specific user it is a generic token that any user could have obtained, but so far no clear way to validate that token actually matches the token for that user.   As i continue to read on google and elsewhere this seems to be a very common concern and even facebook writes of cross-site application token spoofing which from users which is exactly what i'm concerned about.

Comment: Using this to validate the access token returned from login only returns the Application info and not the user level info.  https://graph.facebook.com/app?access_token=

Comment: Ok after countless variations not found on facebook btw on how to call the right GraphAPI URL for token validation i found that the correct URL to get user/email information is "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" and the other URL's only return application level information about the token... and BTW none of this information is readily available in the Facebook Developers documentation on how to do this properly... Everything i needed to resolve this was found outside of Facebook except for the initial asynchronous SDK download and using the login buttons.